# Interior cement walls

Tags: insulation

I want my interior walls to be cement.  Can insulation Foamular 150 rigid foam be added to the cement wall on the exterior side with siding on top of it.

Comment: Yes...but note that any future owner of said house will curse you when it comes time to remodel. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. But there are a lot of details governing this kind of install. Read this: http://www.buildingscience.com/documents/bareports/ba-1204-external-insulation-masonry-walls-wood-framed-walls/view